# Ошибка в TypeScript - тип "3" не может быть назначен для типа "1"

Tags: typescript

Visual Studio Code подсвечивает ошибку

```
[ts]
Тип "[{ name: string; year: number; }, { name: string; year: number; }, { name: string; year: number; }]" не может быть назначен для типа "[{ name: string; year: number; }]".
  Типы свойства "length" несовместимы.
    Тип "3" не может быть назначен для типа "1".
(property) name: string
```

Вот та часть кода

```
cars: [{name: string, year: number}] = [{
    name: 'Ford',
    year: 2015
  }, {
    name: 'Mazda',
    year: 2010
  }, {
    name: 'Audi',
    year: 2017
  }];
```

Что тут не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `cars` объявлена с типом: `[{name: string, year: number}]`

То есть, массив с одним элементом, имеющим строковое поле `name` и числовое поле `number`.

При этом идет попытка присвоить значение, имеющее тип массив с тремя элементами. Данные типы не совместимы, так как имеют разную длину.

Для решения нужно либо указывать квадратные скобки *после* типа элементов:

```
cars: {name: string, year: number}[]
```

Либо воспользоваться `generic` [типом `Array`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array)

```
cars: Array<{name: string, year: number}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, так должно работать отлично

```
interface Car {
    name: string,
    year: number
}

let cars: Array<Car> = [{
    name: 'Ford',
    year: 2015
}, {
    name: 'Mazda',
    year: 2010
}, {
    name: 'Audi',
    year: 2017
}];
```

Comment: А можете объяснить почему мой вариант не работает?

Comment: @Slava, ты объявил переменную типа _массив с одним элементом_, а попытался присвоить ей значение типа _массив с тремя элементами_.

Answer (score 2):

`cars: {name: string, year: number}[]` - в ts массив в типах обозначается как [] в конце строки