# Проблема в компиляции при создании массива в Angular

Tags: массивы, typescript, компиляция, angular

Есть массив "cars" который выводит string как название и number как год выпуска. В браузере все компилирует как нужно, все подгружает но при этом в консоли выдает ошибку: "Type '3' is not assignable to type '1'." В чем может заключаться данная проблема, и так как я в ангуляре новичок, готов посмотреть на каком-то примере!

Сам код:

```
 cars : [{ name: string, year: number }] = [{
name: 'Audi',
year: 2000
 }, {
name: 'VolksWagen',
year: 2003
 }, { 
name: 'BMW',
year: 2005
 }];
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR in src/app/cars/cars.component.ts(13,3): error TS2322: Type '[{ name: string; year: number; }, { name: string; year: number; }, { name: string; year: number; }]' is not assignable to type '[{ name: string; year: number; }]'.


 Types of property 'length' are incompatible.  
 Type '3' is not assignable to type '1'
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Дубликат: [Ошибка в TypeSctipt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820430/186999)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 cars : Array<{ name: string, year: number }> = [{
name: 'Audi',
year: 2000
 }, {
name: 'VolksWagen',
year: 2003
 }, { 
name: 'BMW',
year: 2005
 }];
```

Или так

```
 cars : { name: string, year: number }[] = [{
name: 'Audi',
year: 2000
 }, {
name: 'VolksWagen',
year: 2003
 }, { 
name: 'BMW',
year: 2005
 }];
```